# What's the "one more big item" referenced in the Meteor 0.8 release announcement?

Tags: meteor

The blog post announcing Meteor 0.8 (https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/03/27/meteor-080-introducing-blaze) references one more big item before the 1.0 release. The Meteor Trello has a whole bunch of things slated for 1.0 -- which one is the big item?

Comment: I suspect it's packaging and meteorite integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the Meteor Packaging System. There's a Devshop tech talk by Ekate Kuznetsova (core dev) from March 27th that shows a [first look at the Meteor Packaging System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOdLlvmJgRk).  ([Meteor YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/meteorvideos))

(Here's a playlist of the [entirety of the livestream](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLTUf4ytkmI8Q2P5v5keK7t9snN0qhnZC7).)